# Viewing multiple 3D file formats in one program

Tags: 3d-modeling, viewer

I want a multi-3d-format-file browser.

I'm looking for a program that has the following features:

- Similar to ACDSee or Irfan View which allows browsing files with 3D geometry or files produced by Blender
- Very easy to use (this it is very important)
- It would be nice if such program was portable, but it is not necessary.
- No trial version.

**What I found so far**

- [3D-No Plugins](http://www.thoro.de/page/3dnp-introduction-en), IIUIC it is for online browsing or for being a interactive tool on website (like flash or java programs)
- [Octaga, Web 3D viewer of VRML](http://download.cnet.com/Octaga-Player/3000-6677_4-10336579.html), which is not what I need
- [MeshLab, portable open source program for editing and viewing 3d files](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/)
- 3D Exploration, shareware
- [some other 3d viewers](http://www.planit3d.com/source/software_files/viewers.html)
- [GeeXLab](http://www.geeks3d.com/geexlab/) can also be used to view models

Comment: well, I think he wants a multi-3d-format-file browser...

Comment: @kokbira Yes I do want this program. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hard to answer precisely without having more details about about the 3d formats you intend to use (Blender can export in a variety of formats). Because of the total absence of standards for 3d file formats, this is a big deal, as no software will handle all the hundreds of possible formats.

Also could you be more specific about what you want to do: drag-and-drop files to the main window, rotating objects independently, etc.

That said, if you limit yourself to a specific file format, whatever it is, you can use a pipeline to convert to a "quite standard" file format (to me .ply, .stl. or .wrl), and then import the converted files to a software used as a viewer. Easy-to-use is quite relative when it comes to 3d, so the better is to try, my pick was meshlab, but it has a lot more functions than just browsing and it can be confusing.

Converting to VRML and viewing in an internet browser may be a possibility as well.

Well, that was a vague answer indeed. But I think there is no ultimate tool for what you want. I personnally use at least 10 different software for my 3d data (coming from different sources).

Answer (score 1):

[F3D](https://gitlab.kitware.com/f3d/f3d/-/releases) can open many 3D file formats, including glTF, stl, obj, vtk.

F3D is a free, opensource VTK based software.

```
f3d file.gltf
```